# Angular 7, How to read the data from srt or csv files imported from input, and save in array?

Tags: javascript, angular, filereader

thank you for everyone contributing their time for me.
Im trying to upload files ( csv or srt ) through Input box,
and save to array. I succeed READING files on console, but impossible to save to array.
How am I possible to do it?
Please anyone help me.
Here is my codes.

```
  public onFilechange(event: any) {
 
    let fileReader = new FileReader()
    //fileReader.readAsText(event.target.files[0])

    let result: any
    fileReader.onload = function (event) {
      result = (event.target as any).result
      return result
    }
    this.temporarySavingSubtitle = fileReader.readAsText(event.target.files[0])
    console.log(this.temporarySavingSubtitle) 
  }
```

I was hoping I see the result on console log but nothing shows up.
Please help!

Comment: Does moving your `console.log` to the `onload` show you the result?

Comment: @Phix Yes, when the console.log is inside of the onload, it showed me the result.

Comment: I'd say that's your problem then. The `onload` is asynchronous and you can't access the data outside that block

Comment: @Phix Yes. Thats why I wanna know how to access the data from outside...?

Comment: You can't, unless you wrap it in a promise. There's a lot of resources here that go over async issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

From the code, I didn't found the method to get the data from file(something like stream). I believe you need the js-xlsx.js(also other library) to parse the file stream to json. When you get the json, save to array as you mentioned.

Some key code for single sheet.

```html
import * as xlsx from 'xlsx';

const _readExcelAsync = (file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (event) => {
            const data = event.target.result,
                wb = xlsx.read(data, { type: 'binary' }),
                result = {};
            wb.SheetNames.forEach(sheet => {
                const roa = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(wb.Sheets[sheet], { header: 1 });
                if (roa.length) result[sheet] = roa;
            });
            resolve(Object.values(result)[0]);
        };
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    });
}

export async function processFile(file) {
    try {
        return await _readExcelAsync(file);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

const content = yield call (processFile, file); // file is event.target.files[0]
```